# pip3 installed library can't be found for python execution in terminal

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, jupyter-notebook

I installed tensorflow by using pip3, tensorflow also appears in the pip3 list, but when I try to import tensorflow by executing tensorflow in terminal, it says it cannot find the module tensorflow. when I start jupyter notebook, tensorflow import works fine. what can be the reason? I checked the sys.executable value in terminal and jupyter both. In terminal, it is '/usr/local/bin/python3', in jupyter it is '/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7'.

Answer (score 0):

Enyang,there is high chance that the default is auto set to this path by jupyter. i faced a lot of problems having 2 python environments.
here are the troubleshooting trials:

trial 1:

> try with `pip` and `pip3` both and use argument `-t, --target <dir>`

trial 2:

> its the case that jupyter notebook has tweaked your `python pip3` try changing pip default location.

trial 3 [will work for sure]:

> manually copy paste to merge libraries in python installed path/s.

- trial 4 [obvious]:

> try `venv` (virtual environment) and import your requirements from working version of `pip freeze`